Exercise 1.3 in Anton Deitmar‘s "A first course in Harmonic Anaylsis" , 2nd Edition
I am learning the Fourier Analysis, but I don't how to solve the following problem:
Let $C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ contains all periodic, continuous, complex-valued functions on $[0,1)$
Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$
For $y > 0$, let
$$
\omega(y) = \int_0^1 |f(t+y) - f(t)|dt
$$
Show that the Fourier coefficients $c_k$ of $f$ satisfy
$$
|c_k| \leq \frac{1}{2}\omega(\frac{1}{2k})
$$
for $k \not = 0$
(Hint: Use the fact that $c_k = - \int_0^1 f(t) e^{-2\pi ki (t - \frac{1}{2k})}dt$)

What have you tried so far?

I guess it may related to the Bessel Inequality, but I have no clue where to start...

Thanks, I have edited the title

There is a factor of $i$ missing in the exponential in the hint. It should be $c_{k} = -\int_{0}^{1}f(t)e^{-2\pi ik(t-\frac{1}{2k})} , dt$.

Thanks, my bad, I have fixed that

Fix $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$. To show the hint, you can show that $e^{-2\pi ikt} = -e^{-2\pi ik(t-\frac{1}{2k})}$ for each $t\in [0,1]$ and use this to conclude that $c_{k} = -\int_{0}^{1}f(t) e^{-2\pi ik(t-\frac{1}{2k})}\, {\rm d}t$. Once you have this, you can perform a substitution combined with the fact that $f$ is periodic to obtain that $c_{k} = -\int_{0}^{1}f(t+\frac{1}{2k}) e^{-2\pi ikt}\, {\rm d}t$. As $c_{k} = \frac{1}{2}(c_{k} + c_{k})$, you can express $c_{k}$ as half the sum of two different expressions of the term, one of which is the definition of $c_{k}$ and the other being one of the expressions obtained above. The result now follows by standard properties of the integral.

Thanks for Miller, and I will post the entire answer below:
First consider
$$
-\int f(t) e^{2\pi ki (t - \frac{1}{2k})}
$$
$$
= - \int f(t) e^{2\pi k i t} (e^{-\pi i })  = \int f(t) e^{2\pi k i t} = c_k
$$
~
On the other hand, we have
$$
-\int_0^1 f(t) e^{2\pi k i (t - \frac{1}{2k})} = 
-\int_0^1 f\left(t+\frac{1}{2k}\right)e ^{2\pi k i t}
$$
Then we have
$$
2c_k = \int e^{2\pi k i t} \left(f(t) -  f\left(t + \frac{1}{2k}\right)\right) < \int |f\left(t + \frac{1}{2k}\right) - f(t)|
$$
